# Calculating Empirical Risk using LIBSVM and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am trying to understand how to calculate empirical risk using MATLAB and LIBSVM's MATLAB bindings. I have Y outcomes (1,100) labeled as either -1 or +1, and 10D observations given by X (100,10). I then call `svmtrain` to get my model. The empirical risk is given by the following equation:

[image: Empirical Risk]

based on the values I receive from `svmtrain` how do I get f(xi, alpha)?

Here is what I have so far:

```
params = sprintf('-s 0 -t 0 -c %d', C); 
%X1 and Y1 are values I generate
m1 =  svmtrain(Y1, X1, params);
y = diag(Y1(m1.sv_indices));
x = X1(m1.sv_indices, :);
alpha = m1.sv_coef;
w = alpha'*y*x;
```

Comment: Just as a note: `fitcecoc`, `templateSVM` and `predict` are the newer versions for SVM in MATLAB.

Comment: What is the value of `alpha` for the training samples?

Comment: Why does it matter? But they are   67.9780
   84.2423
  100.0000
  100.0000
   98.8217
  100.0000
 -100.0000
 -100.0000
  -22.6435
 -100.0000
 -100.0000
  -87.2030
  -41.1956

Answer (score 0):

The empirical risk is just the ratio of misclassified training data points. yi is the actual label and f(xi, alpha) is the predicted label of xi based on the trained SVM with support vectors alpha. The formula assumes that labels are either +1 or -1.